# How to build an efficient multiple query function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to write a function in plpgsql that would allow me to query my database efficiently. There are not enough building blocks about plpgsql that would allow me to finish/debug my case, which is the following:

Case:

My database contains more than 50 million records, which consist of text, themes and metadata.
It is only very structured description data, containing sentences such as
"a big brown trunk in a location" or "an incredible different approach" tsvector would provide the highest match entry if every word is spelled correctly regardless or the order, it fails if user miss spells. I used pg_tgrm as a fallback for it which would match using similarity() or word_similarity() If I order the result accordingly

I have indexed two columns using pg_tgrm and tsvector.
I want to be able to have a function lookup(user_text, user_theme) that returns records by matching user theme and input to text indexing methods pg_tgrm or tsvector.

In pseudocode:

```
func lookup(user_input text, user_theme text) -> [score, record]:
var user_input_tsquery <- replace_char(user_input, ' ', ' & ')

if user_theme in database:
    subdatabase <- A set of entries where database.theme = user_theme

    var record <- subdatabase.tsvector = user_input_tsquery
    var result_rank <- rank(subdatabase.tsvector = user_input_tsquery)

    if record is not empty:
        return [result_rank, record]

    else
        var record <- subdatabase.pg_tgrm = user_input
        var simil <- similarity(subdatabase.pg_tgrm = user_input)
        return [simil, record]
else
    var record <- database.tsvector = user_input_tsquery
    var result_rank <- rank(database.tsvector = user_input_tsquery)

    if record is not empty:
        return [result_rank, record]

    else
        var record <- database.pg_tgrm = user_input
        var simil <- similarity(database.pg_tgrm = user_input)
    return [simil, record]
```

plpgsql is really difficult to handle.
I have tried writing the function by small parts of my query function, but just trying to debug how to compose the return value or whether I require TABLE or SETOF as a composed record output is frustrating.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lookup_test(user_input text, user_theme text) RETURNS TABLE AS $$
DECLARE user_input_ts text;
DECLARE ress TABLE;
DECLARE result TABLE(score double, summary text);
BEGIN
SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(user_input), ' ', ' & ') INTO user_input_ts;

CASE WHEN EXIST(SELECT * from database WHERE theme = user_theme)
    THEN
        CASE
            SELECT * from database WHERE theme = user_theme INTO ress;
            WHEN EXIST(SELECT least(ts_rank(ts_summary, user_input_ts, 32), 1.0) AS score, id_source
                       FROM ress
                       WHERE ts_sumnmary @@ to_tsquery('english', user_input_ts))
            THEN RETURN ress;

           SELECT tgrm_summary <-> user_input as score, *
           FROM ress WHERE tgrm_summary % user_input
        END CASE;
        END;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I have no experience with plpgsql. I use pg_tgrm and tsvector because the former is fuzzy compatible but slow and the latter is really fast but requires an exact typing so I wanted to handle whether I could get a smart result that will use tsvector indexing and if it fails then try with pg_tgrm indexing, furthermore if the user provides a theme, then use it as a way to reduce the amount of entries to look for.

Comment: You should start by defining the exact requirements. Full text search and similarity matching are quite different. What is the condition for a successful match?

Comment: It is only very structured description data. database contains sentences such as  
"a big brown trunk in a location" or "an incredible different approach" tsvector would provide the highest match entry if every word is spelled correctly regardless or the order, it fails if user miss spells. I used pg_tgrm as a fallback for it which would match using similarity() or word_similarity() If I order the result accordingly

Comment: You dont need the `CASE WHEN EXIST(SELECT * from database WHERE theme = user_theme)
    THEN` -->> It is not a crime to try to select non-existing records.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid PL/pgSQL. `DECLARE ress TABLE;` is a syntax error. Are you not using regular PostgreSQL?